# snakemake workflow broken by a rule that produces multiple files

Tags: snakemake

Consider the following snakemake workflow (complete in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/jgte/5e25022fb4a5ce79873622fac34790f7)):

I have a predefined set of parameters that define my workflow lanes:

```
PAR={
  "id_list": range(1,10),
}
```

I need to stage the data, here simulated by creating files with random numbers:

```
rule stage:
  output: "in/{id}.old"
  shell: "echo $RANDOM > {output}"
```

I have a function that collects all the staged file names and an accompanying rule that aggregates the staging step:

```
def get_all_dat(wildcards):
  out=[]
  for i in PAR["id_list"]:
    dat=rules.stage.output[0].format(id=i)
    out.append(dat)
  return out

rule stage_all:
  input: get_all_dat
  output: "in/staged.list"
  shell: "for i in {input}; do echo $i; done > {output}"
```

I definitively do not need the `get_all_dat` function to do something as simple as this example (`expand` on the input of `stage_all` would do that), but i decided to include it here because it matches my actual workflow, where there are a few wildcards and they all need to line up, which this function makes sure of.

Then comes the processing step:

```
rule process:
  input: 
    list="in/staged.list",
    util="process.sh"
  output: "out/{id}.new",
  shell: "./{input.util} $(cat {input.list})"
```

It takes the list of files coming from the `stage_all` rule and passes the contents to the `process.sh` script. This script essentially does some dummy change to `in/{id}.old` and writes to `out/{id}.new`, refer to the [gist](https://gist.github.com/jgte/5e25022fb4a5ce79873622fac34790f7) for the exact code.

*Crucially*, this process reads **all** `in/{id}.old` files and creates **all** `out/{id}.new` files. It is here that the workflow lanes get mangled. As with the `get_all_dat` function, this "processing" is an example; the actual processing in my actual workflow cannot be broken into separate `{id}` lanes.

Next step is "plotting":

```
rule plot:
  input:  "out/{id}.new"
  output: "out/{id}.plot"
  shell: "echo \"plot of $(cat {input})\" > {output}"
```

... which gets its own aggregator (just like the staging step):

```
def get_all_plot(wildcards):
  out=[]
  for i in PAR["id_list"]:
    dat=rules.plot.output[0].format(id=i)
    out.append(dat)
  return out

rule plot_all:
  input: get_all_plot
  output: "out/plotted.list"
  shell: "for i in {input}; do echo $i; done > {output}"
```

The main problem of rule `process` is that each `out/{id}.new` file will initiate a new call to `process.sh`, reading concurrently all `in/{id}.old` files and writing concurrently all `out/{id}.new`, which is not good. I've added some code to `process.sh` to count how many times this script is called, see the [gist](https://gist.github.com/jgte/5e25022fb4a5ce79873622fac34790f7).

Things I've tried:

1. using bash and lock files, as well as flock, to force the extra calls to wait for the lucky first `process.sh` thread to finish and then continue with no error;
2. using `directory("out")` in the `output:` of rule `process`;
3. adding an additional rule connecting `out/{id}.new` to the `directory("out")`:

```
    rule connector:
      input: "out",
      output: "out/{id}.new",
```

Consequences:

1. race conditions galore, there's really no good way to ensure only one `process.sh` is executed and snakemake deletes `out/{id}.new` files (as it should) because it couldn't find them when the corresponding `{id}` `process` rule was first called;
2. the workflow gets broken because there's nothing connecting `out/{id}.new` to the `directory("out")`;
3. `ChildIOException: File/directory is a child to another output:`

My intention is to run the complete workflow with `out/plotted.list` as target, with an arbitrary number of cores (which will all need to wait for the one `process.sh` thread to finish). The reason is that the `process` step is cheap, while the `plot` steps are expensive and `{id}` can have many many values.

Thanks for bearing with me through the long post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
rule process:
    input: 
        list="in/staged.list",
        util="process.sh",
    output: 
        touch('out/staged.list'),
    shell: 
        "./{input.util} $(cat {input.list})"

rule plot:
    input:
        list= 'out/staged.list ',
    output: 
        "out/{id}.plot"
    params:
        id= lambda wc: "out/%s.new" % wc.id,
    shell: 
        r"""
        echo "plot of $(cat {params.id})" > {output}
        """
```

Rule `process` gives in output a single dummy file so it is executed only once but it produces all the necessary files.

Rule `plot` takes in input the dummy file from above so its real input must also be present. The real input file is passed as a parameter.

Next rules should be able to use `"out/{id}.plot"` as normal.

Comment: Excellent, thank you @dariober. One thing I learned today: you can remove files from the DAG by plugging them through params.